# Camunda throws error on local oracle db during startup

Tags: java, oracle, camunda

**UPDATE**, I have found problem , I had h2 in class-path, and camunda was running this on h2

Camunda throws error on local oracle db, db is empty . Flyway script works fine but after that I can see this error on logs.  . When I try to start app(same build) on oracle which is not local (again with clean oracle db) I don't get any error.

Error querying database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

```
### The error may exist in org/camunda/bpm/engine/impl/mapping/entity/Job.xml
### The error may involve org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.JobEntity.selectNextJobsToExecute-Inline
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### SQL: select       RES.*      from ACT_RU_JOB RES      where (RES.RETRIES_ > 0)       and (RES.DUEDATE_ is null or RES.DUEDATE_ <= ?)       and (RES.LOCK_OWNER_ is nu
ll or RES.LOCK_EXP_TIME_ < ?)       and RES.SUSPENSION_STATE_ = 1                 and (      (      RES.EXCLUSIVE_ = 1           and not exists(             select J2.*
from ACT_RU_JOB J2             where J2.PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID_ = RES.PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID_                                           -- from the same proc. inst.
  and (J2.EXCLUSIVE_ = 1)                                                              -- also exclusive             and (J2.LOCK_OWNER_ is not null and J2.LOCK_EXP_TIME
_ >= ?)  -- in progress             )    )     or           RES.EXCLUSIVE_ = 0        )            LIMIT ? OFFSET ?
### Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

        at org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:30)
        at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:150)
        at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:141)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.db.sql.DbSqlSession.selectList(DbSqlSession.java:95)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.db.entitymanager.DbEntityManager.selectListWithRawParameter(DbEntityManager.java:173)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.db.entitymanager.DbEntityManager.selectList(DbEntityManager.java:165)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.db.entitymanager.DbEntityManager.selectList(DbEntityManager.java:161)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.db.entitymanager.DbEntityManager.selectList(DbEntityManager.java:150)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.JobManager.findNextJobsToExecute(JobManager.java:191)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.cmd.AcquireJobsCmd.execute(AcquireJobsCmd.java:54)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.cmd.AcquireJobsCmd.execute(AcquireJobsCmd.java:34)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandExecutorImpl.execute(CommandExecutorImpl.java:24)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContextInterceptor.execute(CommandContextInterceptor.java:104)
        ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1059)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:522)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:257)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:587)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:225)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:53)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:774)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:925)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1111)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4798)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.execute(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4901)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.execute(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1385)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor104.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:114)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy144.execute(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.PreparedStatementHandler.query(PreparedStatementHandler.java:63)
        at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.RoutingStatementHandler.query(RoutingStatementHandler.java:79)
        at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BatchExecutor.doQuery(BatchExecutor.java:93)
        at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.queryFromDatabase(BaseExecutor.java:324)
        at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.query(BaseExecutor.java:156)
        at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:109)
        at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:83)
        at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:148)
        ... 19 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Camunda, but the query shown in the log is indeed not properly ended.

```
LIMIT ? OFFSET ?
```

This looks like [Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/queries-limit.html). The [Oracle top-n syntax](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/row-limiting-clause-for-top-n-queries-12cr1) would be:

```
offset ? rows fetch next ? rows only
```

Comment: Thank you I have found problem, There was a h2 db in classpath. and this query was running on h2